# Integrated Discrimination Index (IDI) in Stata

Tags: stata

I'm getting two very different results for integrated discrimination improvement (IDI).

If I use the nriidi.pkg package and run `idi` I get this output

```
    . idi totaloutcome grace_prob, prvars(allelecount)

----------------------------------------------------
      IDI |     Estimate     Std. Err.       P-value
 ----------+-----------------------------------------
           |     -0.01116       0.00430       0.00946
 ----------------------------------------------------
```

But when I use the `idi` from Mark Lunt's program

```
 . net from http://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/mark.lunt

 . idi totaloutcome allelecount grace_prob

 Integrated Discrimination Improvement for allelecount = 0.0017
 Standard Error                                        = 0.0022
 z                                                     = 0.7615
 P-value (one-sided)                                   = 0.2232
 P-value (two-sided)                                   = 0.4464
```

Can anyone explain why this might be occurring or indicate why one package might be better than other?

Comment: Use `net from http://www.ucr.uu.se/sv/images/stories/downloads` for nriidi.pkg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Various issues are bundled together here.

1. Why are there two `idi` programs? Simple: two authors working independently wrote two programs with the same name and then published their programs on their own websites. There is no mechanism to stop this happening. How could there be? Had the authors both attempted to publish through the *Stata Journal* or on the SSC site (`help ssc` for information), the second-posting author would have been asked to change the name of any program that clashed with a pre-existing program on the same site. But no-one is obliged to publish in either of those ways. (Also, using `search` or `findit` an author could look for published programs with a given name on the internet to avoid clashes.)
2. How do you work with the two programs together then? You could copy the two programs into separate directories or folders and move between them. A better approach is to change the name of at least one of the two programs.

   - For example, I could install the `idi` program from Mark Lunt by going in Stata

     ```
     . copy http://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/mark.lunt/idi.ado idi_l.ado
     ```
   - I then need to edit the program file `idi_l.ado` so that a header line reads `program idi_l`
   - You would need to edit the corresponding help file too, although you could access it remotely by using `type` in the style of the `copy` command above.
   - If this is new to you, let me stress that these are Stata commands; no browser is needed, although people in some places will not be able to do this if they are behind a firewall.
3. Why are the programs producing different answers? The answer is simply that you must look at the code. Stata is open source here as far as comparing the two ado files is concerned and is thus exactly like R in this respect. The main difference between the programs is that after running two `logistic` commands the Byberg program gets standard errors from two calls to `ci` while the Lunt program gets a standard error from a call to `ttest` with the `unequal` option. The two results will often be close, but they could be rather different. As @Metrics points out, you should use `viewsource` or a favourite text editor to look at the code.
4. Is one program better? This is difficult to judge but my personal view is that the Lunt program is better written and is of high quality compared with Stata standards. The Byberg program does some unnecessary things and most importantly does not handle `if` and `in` qualifiers.
5. What about the OP's results? We cannot see the OP's data so cannot comment.

To make comparison easier, I rewrote the Byberg program earlier but do not guarantee to answer further questions on it!

```
 *! 1.0.0 NJC 9 Aug 2013 
 * modifying idi (Liisa Byberg) from http://www.ucr.uu.se/sv/images/stories/downloads
 program idi_b, rclass  
 version 10.1
 syntax varlist(numeric min=2) [if] [in] , PRvars(varlist numeric min=1)

 quietly {
     marksample touse
     tokenize "`varlist'" 
     args out
     tempvar pred1 pred2 diffpred 
     tempname mdiffprednonevents sediffprednonevents mdiffpredevents sediffpredevents
     tempname idi seidi zidi pidi

     logistic `varlist' if `touse'
     predict `pred1' if `touse' 
     logistic `varlist' `prvars'  if `touse'
     predict `pred2' if `touse' 
     gen `diffpred' = `pred2' - `pred1'

     ci `diffpred' if `out' == 0 
     scalar `mdiffprednonevents' = r(mean)
     scalar `sediffprednonevents' = r(se)
     ci `diffpred' if `out' == 1
     scalar `mdiffpredevents' = r(mean)
     scalar `sediffpredevents' = r(se)

     scalar `idi' =  `mdiffpredevents' - `mdiffprednonevents'
     scalar `seidi' =  sqrt(`sediffprednonevents'^2 + `sediffpredevents'^2)
     scalar `zidi' = `idi'/`seidi'
     scalar `pidi' = 2*(1-normal(abs(`zidi')))
   }

   di _n "IDI" 
   di "  Estimate  "   %9.5f `idi'
   di "  Std. Err. "   %9.5f `seidi' 
   di "  z         "   %9.5f `zidi' 
   di "  P-value   "   %9.5f `pidi' 

   return scalar idi_b_p = `pidi' 
   return scalar idi_b_z = `zidi' 
   return scalar idi_b_se = `seidi' 
   return scalar idi_b = `idi' 

   end
```

Answer (score 1):

Both give the same answer. For example, see below using the `cancer` data from Stata.

```
sysuse cancer
```

For Pent `idi` command:

```
Syntax

        idi outcomevar new_marker varlist [if] [in]


The command idi calculates the Integrated Discrimination Improvement (IDI) due to
    a new marker new_marker, where the old model predicted outcomevar from varlist.
    The definition of the IDI is given by Pencina et al (2008). It can be thought of
    as the average improvement in sensitivity across all possible cutoffs.

idi died drug age

Integrated Discrimination Improvement for drug = 0.2044
Standard Error                                 = 0.0575
z                                              = 3.5554
P-value (one-sided)                            = 0.0002
P-value (two-sided)                            = 0.0004
```

In above example, new marker is drug, so probably you are testing the improvement due to that:

For the `idi` from Byberg:

```
Syntax

    idi depvar varlist1 [, options]


    options                  description
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Main

      prvars(varlist2)        variable list of new predictor variables

 prvars() is not optional; see below.


Description

    idi calculates the integrated discrimination improvement, which is, as is nri, a
    measure that compares the discrimination ability between two logistic regression
    prediction models. The command assumes a binary numerical depvar and two sets of
    numerical and/or categorical covariates for the two models. The xi function is not
    yet available and dummy variables for categorical covariates with more than two
    categories need to be specified by the user.
    Output are estimated IDI with standard error and p value for test of the null
    hypothesis that IDI in the population is zero.
    Also see: nri
```

.

```
idi died age, prvars(drug)

----------------------------------------------------
      IDI |     Estimate     Std. Err.       P-value
----------+-----------------------------------------
          |      0.20436       0.05748       0.00038
----------------------------------------------------
```

Here, the new marker is as `prvars`.

Comment: I have replicated what was done with the cancer dataset and I do indeed get the same answer both ways, but with my data I get different outputs which does not make any sense to me. Is there any reason why that should be?

Comment: I am not sure why these both packages use same `idi`; it is not possible to run one without uninstalling another (may be there is an easy way to handle that). The suggestion for you is to see what requirements they have in terms of variables. For example, the `idi`command from Byberg assumes a binary numerical depvar and two sets of numerical and/or categorical covariates for the two models.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Lundt program doesn't say anything specific about variable requirements. From Byberg specifies my variables shouldn't be a problem. Is there an easy way to see how each program is performing their calculations ? I'm thinking if I can see the code I can see how they are calculating their numbers and I'll see where the discrepancy lies. I know in R you can see the actual coding for each program.

Comment: you can use `viewsource idi.ado` to see the actual code. You may want to try `set trace on` for that (you need to `set trace off` after you are done)